# having difficulties with query validation

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I created a scheduling function using code igniter calendar. what i did was the user can choose a day of the month and insert his/her schedule i.e 1:00pm - 2:00pm
i'am saving the time start and date in timestamp format. My problem was i needed to validate that the users second inserted schedule for the same date is not in between his previous schedules. so if he already save 1:00 pm - 2:00pm the user cannot insert schedule between 1:00pm - 2:00pm. BTW schedule will always be a 1 hour duration! I have no idea on how to do it.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: use `callbacks` in codeigniter for form validation

Comment: Use can use INSERT SELECT syntax. Provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements and someone will probably show you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Between operator

```
$this->db->where("$newdate BETWEEN $startdate AND $enddate");
```

and fetch the record if this query fetching the record then don't let user insert new date .

try this also.

```
$this->db->where('$newdate >=', startdate);
$this->db->where('$newdate<=', enddate);
```